# unexpected regex match with IGNORECASE

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have an unexpected match using the following code.

I tested the regex on several pages online including the `re.IGNORECASE` option and no one gives a match, but when I run it, I get a match on `'PA'`

```
import re
def main():
    Names =['PA','SB','PA Solid','SB Solid']

    for Name in Names:
        print (Name)
        print (re.search(Name,'PartBody|Part_Body',re.IGNORECASE))
```

This is the output, I expect no match on any item in the list.

```
PA
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff682876030>
SB
None
PA Solid
None
SB Solid
None
```

Comment: You swapped pattern with input. Use `re.search('PartBody|Part_Body', Name,re.IGNORECASE)` or `re.search('Part_?Body', Name, re.I)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you swapped the pattern.your pattern should be like **re.search(pattern, string[], flags])**

```
names = ['PA','SB','PA Solid','SB Solid']
for name in names:
    print("Name:",name)
    print(re.search(r'PartBody|Part_Body', name,re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output:

```
('Name:', 'PA')
None
('Name:', 'SB')
None
('Name:', 'PA Solid')
None
('Name:', 'SB Solid')
```

Comment: That was a part of code I inherited from a python expert saying this runs for a long time without any problems...2 hrs debugging an testing my part of the code niw this! Thanks to Naresh and Wiktor!